# It is possible to comment and uncomment block of code from DOM tree using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, comments

I would like to comment and uncomment part of DOM tree. I have:

```
<div id="otherDiv"></div>
<div id="commentThisDiv"></div>
<div id="anotherDiv"></div>
```

And when user click on button, jQuery should comment `#commentThisDiv` and return:

```
<div id="otherDiv"></div>
<!--<div id="commentThisDiv"></div>-->
<div id="anotherDiv"></div>
```

Second click should uncomment this DIV.

Yes, I want to hide this element but for some reasons it MUST be a comment. I can't use other functions, like `.hide()` or `.attr('style', 'display:none;')`.

If clear jQuery doesn't support it, maybe I should use an extension?

Comment: @Blazemonger I couldn't found a satisfy answer so if you think that this question was already answered, please give me here title of duplicated question.